# Is the power consumption of a fan dependent on the temperature of the air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A fan keeps air circulating in a closed loop at a constant volumetric flow rate (like in a closed return wind tunnel). Is the power consumption of the fan dependent on the temperature of the circulating air, i.e. does the power consumption of the fan increase/decrease when the circulating air gets colder/hotter?

I think that when the air gets so cold that the flow velocity reaches the speed of sound ($Ma ≈ 1$), shock waves occur and that should significantly increase the power consumption of the fan. But for flow velocities below Mach 0.3 there should be no change in power consumption when the temperature of the air changes. What do you think?

Comment: Why would cooling the air increase the flow velocity?

Comment: That probably depends on the construction of the fan. Higher temperature under same pressure means the air is thinner and give less resistance, so the rpm should go up. But higher temperature means also higher ohmic resistance in the motor wire, so the current and torque should go down. Sounds like an experimental question - try to measure the power as a function of the air temperature for a particular fan.

Comment: @JMac: Cooling would not increase the flow velocity but the Mach number of the flow since the speed of sound decreases with decreasing temperature.

Comment: @JánLalinský Then you would have to decide if that's worth considering, or if you could get away with a belt-drive system where the motor could be thermally isolated from the duct.  So in theory you could partially ignore ohmic resistance if you accounted for it when designing this system.  But then this becomes an engineering problem.

Comment: @JánLalinský: The idea is to have a closed system (like a closed return wind tunnel). Changing the temperature of the air does change the pressure but not the density of the circulating air, thus the air isn't "thinner". The efficiency of the motor (or wire) is not important here. Before I do an experiment, I wanted to check if there are arguments from a theoretical perspective that would give an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in temperature would **not** primarily affect the power consumption of the fan, unless you think about change in resistance.

The power consumption of a fan motor $P = \frac{V^2}{R}$, where $V$ is the line voltage and $R$ is the resistance of the motor.

As you can see, both $V$ and $R$ are constant, and independent of change in temperature of air. So, $P$ would remain unchanged on changing the temperature of air. On increasing or decreasing air temperature, the coefficient of viscosity $\eta$ of air changes, due to which the Viscous force acting on the fan blades changes. Thus, the velocity of fan blade may vary, but the **power consumption would remain the same**.

You may say that on increasing temperature, the resistance changes to $R_0 + \alpha \Delta T$, where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of change in resistance of wires and components. So, the power consumption will also change. In that case, the answer is a **yes**. *But that would be very negligible.*